# java/html form submission -> request.getParameter("..."); only returns the first portion of a string?

Tags: java, html, forms

i'm unsure how to phrase my question. but I've got an html form submitting data to a java backend which handles the data and submits it to the database.

the java form grabs each of my values using the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` library

so in order to grab the value of:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName">
```

In the java page I would do:

```
String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
```

this works great, however if my input is two words, it will only return the first one.

so say i put in "John George" for my firstName,
the java page will only receive "John".

I can't figure out why.

Form Code:

```
   foot =  "<form method='POST' action='Submit'>";
    //path to java servlet 
    foot += "<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value="+firstName+">"; 
    foot += "<input type='hidden' name='lastName' value="+lastName+">"; 
    foot += "<input type='hidden' name='school' value="+school+">"; 
    foot += "<input type='hidden' name='email' value="+email+">";
```

Comment: it doesn't work with either of them.
right now i'm using POST tho

Comment: I don't know, works on my end. simple form with post, hitting my servlet doPost(request, response) getting the parameter.

Comment: hmm.. could it be that I'm actually using hidden form types?
"<input type='hidden' value="+firstName"+">";

Comment: Could you post all your code from the form?

Comment: yeah ok,
so what I'm actually doing, is that I have the entire form dynamically generated using javascript.

when everything is finished, I use JS to create a hidden form that will be submitted"


    foot = "<form method='POST' action='Submit'>";//path to java servlet
    foot += "<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value="+firstName+">";
    foot += "<input type='hidden' name='lastName' value="+lastName+">";
    foot += "<input type='hidden' name='school' value="+school+">";
    foot += "<input type='hidden' name='email' value="+email+">";

Comment: Try to use "text" fields and see if that makes a difference although it should't but to be sure.

Comment: mmm... the formatting is messed up in my previous comment.

but what happens is i dynamically generate the form. and submit it through javascript.

what I just realized is that when i create the form, i do something like

"<input type='hidden' value= " + value + ">";

but the entire value of "value" isn't input into the form input

Comment: just fyi next time just edit your question so it's easier to read.

Comment: yeah this is my first time posing to stackOverFlow
the formatting in these comments is kind of weird too.

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly though!
I think I can figure it out from here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each attribute value should be wrapped with quotes. Your attributes are wrapped in quotes (which most browsers can deal with) but your value attributes don't have any quote wrapping. So your output is looking something like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value=John George>
```

Because the value is not wrapped in quotes therefore the browser is interpreting "John" to be the value of the value attribute and "George" to be a new attribute without a value.

Wrapping your value attribute in quotes should fix this.

```
foot =  "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"Submit">";
//path to java servlet 
foot += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"firstName\" value=\""+firstName+"\">"; 
foot += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lastName\" value=\""+lastName+"\">"; 
foot += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"school\" value=\""+school+"\">"; 
foot += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"email\" value=\""+email+"\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is pretty simple: Look at the HTML source code in your browser and you'll see:

```
<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value=John George>
```

So you have an `input` element with 4 attributes and the last attribute is `George`.

Solution:

1. Don't forget to quote your strings
2. **NEVER** forget to HTML escape text values which you add to the HTML

The second point allows mischievous people to do very nasty things with your web site. See [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

So the correct code would be:

```
foot += "<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value='"+StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(firstName)+"'>";
```

`StringEscapeUtils` can be found in [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Answer (score 0):

Given that `firstName = "John George"` this: `"<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value="+firstName+">";` renders in HTML to

```
<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value=John George>
```

So "George" is interpreted as attribute. Please try to add the quotes correctly:

```
"<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value='" + firstName + "'>"
```